# Flutter problem cloud-firestore dependency

Tags: android, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a flutter app that works fine, but when I add the cloud-firestore dependency, it crashes with:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:preDebugBuild'.
Android dependency 'android.arch.lifecycle:runtime' has different version for the compile (1.0.0) and runtime (1.1.1) classpath. You should manually set the same version via DependencyResolution
```

Here my pubspec.yaml

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

    #FIRESTORE
    cloud_firestore: ^0.9.0
```

How can I fix this?

Regards, Diego

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that I needed more config than just adding the cloud_firestore dependency. I've follow this tutorial https://www.gotut.net/flutter-firestore-tutorial-part-1/

As a summary:

I had to change cloud_firestore: ^0.9.0 to cloud_firestore: ^0.8.2+3.

Pubspec.yaml:

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.0.0-dev.68.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  #FIRESTORE
  cloud_firestore: ^0.8.2+3
```

.android/build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
}
...
subprojects {
    project.configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
            if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support'
                  && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') ) {
                details.useVersion "26.1.0"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

.android/app/build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...        
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This happened because of dependencies conflicting each other. Simply downgrade your cloud_firestore to older version i.e replace **cloud_firestore: ^0.9.0** with   **cloud_firestore: ^0.8.2+1** or  any older version

Comment: Still the same problem... I've tried also ^0.8.1+1 and the same result...

Comment: This should solve the problem...  add the following configuration to android/app/build.gradle

    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force 'com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1'
        resolutionStrategy.force 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
        resolutionStrategy.force 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    }

Comment: I had to add more config to make this work. Check my answer

Answer (score 0):

The setting that I have just got to work for me after wasting to much time:

pubspec.yaml
  firebase_auth: ^0.6.6
  google_sign_in: ^3.2.4
  firebase_core: ^0.2.5+1
  cloud_firestore: ^0.8.2+3

app\build.gradle
  minSdkVersion 21 (was 16)
  and nothing added to dependencies {
   }

project build.gradle
  'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1' (Not 4.2.0 which worked for niegus above)